# Tried cloning Windows 11 Drive, Failed

Tags: windows-11, bsod, clone

I have used a GPartEd boot disk to clone a Windows 11 drive, but it is not booting.

I had the new drive attached by USB and the system booted into GPartEd. 1. Created the same GPT partition table on new drive. 2. Cloned all partitions in physical sequence. 3. Set all volume names and flags as per the original disk.

Putting the new drive into the machine resulted in a windows failure to boot. Literally Blue screen Error 0x00000000, required device not found.

I figure somehow the old disk is required for the system to be satisfied in booting , but it can't be as I'm replacing it.

What am I missing?

- HP Probook 450 G9
- Windows 11 Professional

Comment: 1) Have you tried cloning the partition table 1:1 instead of building it by hand? (sfdisk or dd would work.) There is quite a bit more than what's shown in GParted. And 2) if you run `lsblk -t`, do both the old and new disks show up as having the same logical-sector sizes?

Comment: To be fair I wouldn't have known that was possible. I guess that is not something GPrted or anything like it would do? Like is it just a simple linux function?

Comment: If the drives are of the same size, or the replacement is larger, it's far safer to clone the whole drive at once, https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "anything like it"... Graphical partitioning tools usually do not expose the full information, but e.g. `sfdisk --dump` from CLI would do the job fine. (Both MBR and GPT have a 'partition type GUID' that GParted _kind of_ exposes via its custom "flags" system, and GPT also has the 'disk GUID' and 'partition unique GUID' that GParted does not expose at all – those would be the main differences.)

Comment: Also, 3) are both disks of the same _connection type_? That is, are they both SATA, or are they both NVMe, or such?

Comment: They are both NVMe M.2, one installed natively to the motherboard, the other USBC attached.

Comment: I've never really gotten to the bottom of what is real and what isn't with partitioning. At some point the bytes all need to be in an expected order, with boundaries identified. The MBR vs GPT must be a parent to the partition format, but with flags, alignment, cluster size etc.  I just don't know where the abstractions end. What is the actual byte order from address zero up and can any software utility actually access it raw? Surely that order, duplicated to the new disk, should look identical to the OS.

Comment: It would be simpler to clone the entire disk with a product that adjust to different disk sizes and is Windows-oriented (not GPartEd).

Comment: @harrymc I can't heartily disagree, but fundamentally I can't see why it must be this hard. Duplicate the bytes surely is simple enough to work with anything.

Comment: The problem is knowing which bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Windows bootloader uses a configuration file, called the BCD, to store information it needs to boot. One of those pieces of information is the UUID of the partition it's supposed to boot to. But because the partition UUID on the new drive isn't the same as the one on the old drive, it cannot find the configured partition.

If you have a Windows installer flash drive, you should be able to trivially fix the issue by running [bcdboot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bcdboot) :

`bcdboot path\to\windows`

That will rebuild the bootloader configuration using the correct disk and partition information.